# while loop has overlapping values after retrieving from database

Tags: php, css, sql

> CSS:

```
.image-container {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.image-questionid {
left: 500px;
width: 130px;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

> Here is HTML

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $questID = $row['two_three_id'];
    $factor1 = $row['factor1'];
    $factor2 = $row['factor2'];
    ?>

    <div class="image-container">
    <div class = "image-questionid"><u>Question <?php echo $questID; ?></u></div>
    </div>
```

> The above codes is the code that I have written and they seems to be overlapping each other after i retrieved it from the database. How do i hide the other values and only show 1 value at a time?

Comment: You only seem to display the variable `$questID`. What exactly do you mean by overlapping?

Comment: When the databased is called, all the values are displayed. However it overlaps one another.